# How to disable/ hide all buttons after one click on any button (cshtml)

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

i would like to know how to disable/hide all the buttons once user clicks on any of the buttons. I am only allowed to use c# or html. I have found solutions in Javascript but i cannot use it. (i did not upload my razor c# code due to lack of space)

I am creating a program that allows user to vote for any one of the candidates. Once user has clicked and chosen on one candidate, the voting result will be displayed and user should not be allowed to vote again.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elections</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Harry</td>
                    <td><input id="Harry" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Harry" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td><input id="John" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote John" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bryan</td>
                    <td><input id="Bryan" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Bryan" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jack</td>
                    <td><input id="Jack" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Jack" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            @if (result != "")
            {
                <p>@result</p>
            }

            <!--Ensure that user has voted before showing the vote results-->
            @if (voteCheck == true)
            {
                <p>Total Votes: @Session["totalVotes"]</p> <!--using session allows values to be kept even after button click-->
                <p>      Harry: @Session["Harry"]</p>
                <p>       John: @Session["John"]</p>
                <p>      Bryan: @Session["Bryan"]</p>
                <p>       Jack: @Session["Jack"]</p>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume that the page is submitted, and on the next viewing the buttons need to be disabled: update your form handler to set a flag to disable all buttons, an include a check on that flag to hide the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need an action attribute to the form `action="youraction/controller here"`
And in youraction you write some C# code return list of display value ("none" or "")
And in cshtml you add `style="display:@display"`

```
<input id="Harry" name="submit" type="submit" style="display:@display" value="Vote Harry" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a Ternary operator that check the session object and sets the `disabled` property accordingly.

```
<input id="Harry" @(Session["Harry"] != null ? "disabled" : "") name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Harry" />
```